pywinauto not printing control identifiers
I'm trying to use pywinauto with a software called HELIOSense.

The problem is that i'm not seeing any interesting control identifiers.
pywinauto is only finding the three main buttons of the window (minimize, maximize and close).
Here's my python code :
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application  
import os

app = Application(backend="uia").connect(title="HELIOSense User Application")
main_dlg = app.window(title="HELIOSense User Application")
main_dlg.print_control_identifiers()

Output :
Dialog - 'HELIOSense User Application'    (L360, T134, R1560, B898)
['HELIOSense User Application', 'Dialog', 'HELIOSense User ApplicationDialog']
child_window(title="HELIOSense User Application", control_type="Window")
| 
| TitleBar - ''    (L386, T137, R1550, B167)
| ['TitleBar']
|    | 
|    | Menu - 'Système'    (L368, T142, R390, B164)
|    | ['Menu', 'Système', 'SystèmeMenu', 'Système0', 'Système1']
|    | child_window(title="Système", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
|    |    | 
|    |    | MenuItem - 'Système'    (L368, T142, R390, B164)
|    |    | ['MenuItem', 'Système2', 'SystèmeMenuItem']
|    |    | child_window(title="Système", control_type="MenuItem")
|    | 
|    | Button - 'Réduire'    (L1411, T135, R1458, B167)
|    | ['Réduire', 'Button', 'RéduireButton', 'Button0', 'Button1']
|    | child_window(title="Réduire", control_type="Button")
|    | 
|    | Button - 'Agrandir'    (L1458, T135, R1504, B167)
|    | ['Agrandir', 'Button2', 'AgrandirButton']
|    | child_window(title="Agrandir", control_type="Button")
|    |
|    | Button - 'Fermer'    (L1504, T135, R1551, B167)
|    | ['Button3', 'Fermer', 'FermerButton']
|    | child_window(title="Fermer", control_type="Button")

I also tried with Windows SDK's inspect & changing the backend to win32, but to no avail.
Inspect.exe output :


You do it the right way, but the app doesn't provide sufficient accessibility info to MS UI Automation API. ¯\(ツ)/¯  BTW, is it WPF app? Can you provide the screenshot with Inspect.exe?

@VasilyRyabov yeah haha, it just doesn't provide anything interesting it seems like, I added the screenshot of Inspect.exe in my post. I don't know if it's a WPF app, how can i check?

FrameworkId: "Win32", so it's not a WPF app. :) No luck. Sorry.
